# Should GetHashCode() method take care about null value given as parameter?

Tags: c#, linq, equals, gethashcode

In some C# code, I use `linq` `GroupBy<TSource, TKey>()` method with a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>`.

```
GroupBy(x => x.SomeField, new FooComparer());
```

The field i use as a grouping key can be `null`. As a consequence, i had to add some `null` checks in `Equals()` method :

```
public bool Equals(Foo x, Foo y)
{
    if (x == null && y == null)
       return true;
    else if (x == null && y != null)
       return false;
    else if (x != null && y == null)
       return false;
    else 
       return x.Id == y.Id;
}
```

**The question is : should I do the same in `GetHashCode()` function ?**

```
public int GetHashCode(Foo obj)
{
    if (obj == null)          //is this really needed ?
       return default(int);   //
    else
       return obj.Id;
}
```

Something i do not understand : even with null keys provided in `GroupBy()` method, `GetHashCode()` is never called with a `null` object in obj parameter. Can somebody explain me why ? (is it just "pure chance" because the way `GroupBy()` is implemented and order of the elements i give to it ?)

---

EDIT :

as *caerolus* pointed it out, there is some special checks made in `GroupBy()` implementation.

I checked in `ILSpy` and `GroupBy()` is implemented with a `Lookup<TKey, TElement>`

Here is the revelant function :

```
internal int InternalGetHashCode(TKey key)
{
    if (key != null)
    {
        return this.comparer.GetHashCode(key) & 2147483647;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: maybe `GroupBy` automatically puts together all objects that are `null` without even checking?

Comment: How do you have a `GetHashCode()` that accepts a parameter?

Comment: @caerolus : good point. i will look into that direction.

Comment: @MatthewWatson By implementing a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the documentation of `IEqualityComparer<T>.GetHashCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132155.aspx):

> **ArgumentNullException**
>   The type of `obj`  is a reference type and `obj` is **null**.

So this is part of the contract of that interface, and as such you should care. Implement it by throwing `ArgumentNullException` if `obj` is `null`.

You should always adhere to an interface, even if you suspect or can prove that the code will never touch the parts you don't care about. Changes later might introduce code that relies on that behaviour.